# Implement all interface members

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript interface. The problem is it has about 40 members. When I use it and I implement only chosen members I get an error that there are some missing. How to ignore it? Do I have to implement them all? This issue prevents me from casting one type into another.

E.g.

```
interface A {
   // 40 members
}

class B implements A {
   // only 5 members implemented
}

// somewhere in the code
var myVar1: A = something;
var myVar2: B = <B> myVar1; // here an error (can't convert because B has missing some properties and methods:/)
```

Comment: The rule for interfaces in all languages I've encountered is that you have to implement all of its methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in typescript you can mark items as optional:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    address?: string;
}
```

name is required and address is optional for implementation

Comment: You must implement the entire interface but you can make some optional, as shown here. However if you truly want all of some implemented sometimes but then other times you want a different set, you can create something as @SteveFenton shows below

Answer (score 5):

If you promise that you implement an interface, you have to implement it all.

One solution would be to have a base class that implements the 40 properties if you only want to deal with 5 properties in B.

```
interface A {
   propA: string;
   propB: string;
}

class C implements A {
    public propA = "";
    public propB = "";
}

class B extends C {
   public propB = "Example";
}

var myVar1: A;
var myVar2: B = <B> myVar1;
```

Answer (score 4):

40 items in an interface is quite alot.

Also, if you only need 5 for a certain class it indicates a design problem.

An alternative design is to have multiple related interfaces and divide the properties into more logical groups.

```
interface ICar ...
interface IRacingCar : ICar
interface IFlyingCar : ICar
interface IFamilyCar : ICar
```

Then you can have a class that actually implements multiple interfaces.

```
class RaceCar: IRacingCar ...
class FlyingRaceCar: IRaceCar, IFlyingCar ...
class FlyingFamilyCar: IFlyingCar, IFamilyCar ...
```

Also, you should avoid casting from an interface to a specific class unless you are certain the object is actually that class. The problem will occur if you try to use a method of that class that doesn't actually exist if the object is not really that type.